# Changing the applications taskbar name

Tags: desktop-environments, taskbar

Somehow one of my students changed the name of the applications bar from **applications** to **Sandy and Andrea are my BFFs**. Needless to say, I am NOT pleased. How do I go about changing it back to say **applications**?

Comment: I guess you mean gnome-shell desktop environment?

Comment: What do you mean by "application bar" and which application are you talking about? If you don't know how to describe it you're welcome to include a link to a screenshot in your question.

Comment: In general you should not give other people the ability to make permanent changes to any system configuration (outside of their own user profile if any). There are multiple ways to achieve this depending on your particular needs (e. g. students have their own accounts with persistent storage or students get a squeaky clean ephemeral guest account each time they log in).